# intel array building blocks and GPUs

Tags: opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I'm helping a friend in his master thesis involving the parallelization of a chosen algorithm on multiple CPUs (and GPUs if possible) using a metalanguage programming model like intel array building blocks or MetaOcaml.

A Radeon HD7970 will be used if the GPGPU is possible under a metalangage compiler.

He has planed to use intel arbb but we found recently that this project was moved from beta to "whatif" state (I don't know what it mean?!). All downloads (software and documentations) are disabled.

So I have some questions :

**1.** Does the latest intel arbb beta release really support the GPGPU because the only document confirming this is a master thesis:

"Parallel programming on GPU using Intel Array Building Blocks "

http://sdsu-dspace.calstate.edu/handle/10211.10/2355

**2.** Is Intel Arbb canceled and is there another software of library from intel supporting the GPGPU on nvidia or amd gpus ?

Comment: If you were planning on using a Radeon card, you'd likely be using OpenCl for GPGPU. Many Intel chips can support OpenCl in at least two different ways as far as I know (both with the individual cores and with the on chip video processor if the chip has that). I know that the AMD implementation can choose between the GPU and the CPU for OpenCl operation on my machine (no on chip video processor). I know nothing about intel abb.

Answer (score 0):

The best choice would be to work with openCL. You can also take a glimpse at polly for GPGPU: http://polly.llvm.org/documentation/gpgpucodegen.html but it is far from being a reliable project yet.

With openCL, you will be able to parallelize your algorithm on many platforms, including GPGPUs from NVIDIA and AMD, CPUs from AMD, CPUs from intel (although it depends on your OS and your CPU, see: http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk)

You can get started programming in openCL by reading for example this book: "heterogeneous computing with opencl": http://store.elsevier.com/Heterogeneous-Computing-with-OpenCL/Benedict-Gaster/isbn-9780124058941/